# How Laravel Eloquent references the right table

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

I'm currently watching the Laravel Tutorial Episode 7

https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-from-scratch-2017/episodes/7

I created the database and populated its data on the previous episode,

it is only this time, the tutorial introduces model, upon creating the model name "Task" via `php artisan make:model Task`, it automatically connects to my table "tasks" without any clue how  it happened.

So how did a freshly out of the box model knows it?

Comment: It's general standard. If you create table with name plural and Model as singular It automatically connects corresponding table, other wise you need to specify table name in model

Comment: Ok thanks, I got confused for a second there, cause it wasn't explained by the caster himself.

Comment: also please submit it as answer Mr. Sagar so I could close this question.

Comment: okay, As you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's general definition standard.

If you create a table with plural name and create model for this table as singular, then model automatically connects corresponding table, otherwise you should define table name in model like:

```
protected $table = 'task_table';
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a convention Laravel follows. Laravel will search for a table that is the snake cased Model's name in plural unless you indicate another table.

If you generate the model with the migration flag (e.g. `php artisan make:model Task --migration`), it will also create a table with the model's name in plural automatically (in this case, `Tasks`).

You can check more about it in the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent).

> **Table Names**
>
> Note that we did not tell Eloquent which table to use for our Flight
>   model. **By convention, the "snake case", plural name of the class will
>   be used as the table name unless another name is explicitly specified.**
>   So, in this case, Eloquent will assume the Flight model stores records
>   in the  flights table. You may specify a custom table by defining a
>   table property on your model (...)